# On Tumblr How To Show ShareThis Widget On Whole Site, But Pages?

Tags: widget, tumblr, sharethis

I have a Tumblr blog, I have added ShareThis codes,

But it is appearing on pages also, how to hide that widget on pages?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure to wrap your share widget in `{block:Date}{/block:Date}`. Since Pages don't have dates assigned to them (like your regular posts do) you share widget will not be rendered!

Comment: Thank you very much! I havent try it, but I think it will!